# Where should be the right location of the word "never" in the sentence?

Tags: negation, syntax

Where should be the right location of the word "never" in the following sentence?

> 1)  "We **never** did not have a lecture by this lecturer"
>
> 2) "**Never** we did not have a lecture by this lecturer"
>
> 3) We did not have **never** a lecture by this lecturer"?
>
> 4) We did not have a lecture by this lecturer, **never**"

Comment: Double negatives annoy many people.

Comment: It's not clear: did have at least one lecture from this lecturer?

Comment: @StoneyB No, never.

Comment: Why do you want  to use double negation? *We never had a lecture by that person.* is a simple and clear variant.

Comment: Actually I don't, but I'd like to know the answer at least theoretically because my friend asked me about it today and I didn't know the answer. I told him that I'll ask here and then he will see the answer. Now it's interesting for me as well.

Comment: 1 is a very awkward way of saying that you never missed a lecture from this lecturer, or that there were no occasions when this lecturer didn't give a lecture. 2 & 3 are wrong grammatically. 4 means you did not have any lectures from this lecturer, but the "never" on the end is confusing, awkward, arguably wrong, and should be removed. You said in a comment that you did not have any lectures from this lecturer - if you want to state that emphatically then "We did not ever have a lecture from this lecturer" is a better way to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) "We never did not have a lecture by this lecturer"

This means that the lecturer would **always** end up giving you lectures at some rigid and constant frequency throughout your experience. Double negative = affirmative in English.

> 2) "Never we did not have a lecture by this lecturer"
>
> 3) We did not have never a lecture by this lecturer"?
>
> 4) We did not have a lecture by this lecturer, never"

All of these are ungrammatical.

> 2) "Never we did not have a lecture by this lecturer"

There is the antiquated "Never did (subject) (verb)", however. I don't advise using it casually.

> 3) We did not have never a lecture by this lecturer"?

"Never" never goes after its target verb, unless in some nonstandard speech. It goes before it. e.g. "He was **never** permitted to enter this facility!"

> 4) We did not have a lecture by this lecturer, never

Nonstandard.

I'm more familiar with

> We did not have a lecture by this lecturer, ever.

though I do not recommend this in formal writing, ever.

Even better would be

> We did not ever have a lecture by this lecturer.

EDIT: As it seems that your lecturer did not give you any lectures, just *never* alone can negate. It does not have to use do-support.

My preferred sentence would be:

> We ***never*** had a lecture from this lecturer.

Comment: I have heard people say #4.  It might not strictly be correct, but you will often hear people say it as an intensifier, to emphasize the "never-ness", like "I have not smoked marijuana - never, not once."